# Print SVC in document with Java

Tags: java, pdf

I am trying to print a Secure Verification Code in a PDF document using Java.

The problem is to find some examples on google, but I couldn’t find any illustration or theoretical documentation.

All references found in google takes me to [spanish government pages](http://insert%20secure%20verification%20code%20in%20document).

Any help would be appreciated.

---

***More info:***

What is a secure verification code (CSV for its Spanish name, código seguro de verificación)?
 
A secure verification code is a set of digits that serves to uniquely identify an electronic document issued by any Government Directorate.
This code is printed on every single page of the document so that the document can be checked against its original electronic copy to verify its authenticity.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? To modify each page of an existing PDF document with a constant code or to obtain/calculate the secure verification code?

Comment: Obtain/calculate the secure verification code

Comment: "A secure verification code is a set of digits that serves to uniquely identify an electronic document issued by any Government Directorate." It seems that the CSV is only part of official government documents. If you are officially working for the spanish government you should ask your boss or colleagues how to obtain a CSV. Otherwise why should you obtain an official code for non-government documents? Besides that, this question seems to be off-topic because it is not a technical programming question.

Comment: I asked my boss and indeed, is something related to spanish government, I need it because we develope software for public administration. I know that the question seem to be off-topic, but I am asking about the technique to achieve this feature. As I could know, in programming jargon is called **checksum**. I found some example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-checksums)

Comment: Sorry, this is hard for me to understand. If you are developing official software for the administration and adding the CSV code to documents is part of the requirement then the details for calculating or obtaining the CSV should be part of the specification. And I doubt that the CSV is a simple checksum like CRC32. That would be contraproductive for the intended use case (verify the document's authenticity). It is more likely that it is a cryptographic hash with a hidden password or some kind of public-key cryptography.